# Text not centrally aligned in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, text-align

Works fine in Chrome/Safari, but in FF and IE the very bottom black bar text (with copyright) the text is not aligned centrally for some reason.

[Working Demonstration URL](http://69.24.73.172/demos/index.html)

HTML:

```
    <div class="copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2011 Scirra.com.  All rights reserved.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.copyright
{
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

**Edit**

Answer solves the alignment, but firefox only has the horizontal scroll bug:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `.footerWrapper` class. The -20px `margin-bottom` is causing the shift, and setting its overflow to `hidden` fixes it:

[image: https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/113308/widget/screencap_2011-03-01_16-00-00.png]

[Edit] [Larger version of image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/113308/widget/screencap_2011-03-01_16-00-00.png)

Comment: @Alex, not in Firefox unfortunately.

Comment: What version of FF? I was running FF4 beta 10 to get the shot.

Comment: @Tom Gullen It worked for me in Firefox 3.6.13. What are you using?

Comment: Thanks, it does work.  Hard refresh doesn't seem to reload cache which is annoying (in FF).  Thanks again!  This was really bugging me.

Comment: Ahhh one last thing, there is a horizontal scrollbar still though... that needs to go, it scrolls to about 5px of whitespace.  Only in Firefox.

Comment: Hm, not sure what to tell you there. Don't see it in my version. :( Sorry

Comment: I've updated the CSS on the demo page, do you not get horizontal scroll bar in FF?

Comment: No, I don't, but I simulated it by setting the width of the gray element to `101%` and then got rid of it by setting `overflow-x: hidden` to body--however, this means if the page is too wide for someone, they won't get a scrollbar.

Comment: @Brandon thanks for looking anyway.  The overflow x hidden is too much of a hack for the website this early on, especially for such a simple problem!  Not much you can do if it's non repro though

Comment: My friends can all reproduce the scroll bar

Answer (score 2):

You are using Mozilla's box-shadow CSS and this is causing the horizontal scroll bar. It is not a bug but is causing the issue.

Comment: Offset like this:  -moz-box-shadow: -15px 0px 15px #555;  works.  Not perfect but it's a good compromise.  I'll probably remove these and update background image anyway.